# Converting date as timestamp while selecting using Hibernate APIs

Tags: java, hibernate

We have a GUI application which sends around 40 parameters to the DB.
Based on these parameters a dynamic query is generated to fetch data. Number of fields that needs to be selected remains the same, only where condition differs.
Hibernate criteria API is used to form dynamic queries.  We are using SQLMX as the database running on HP Nonstop server.
Certain dates need to be stored as 0001-01-01. Now, while selecting this field (DATE datatype), application displays this as 2001-01-01. When query is run from RazorSQL also, we are seeing incorrect results.
I could resolve this issue in RazorSQL by doing "select (cast(date1 as timestamp) from table". This gives date correctly, but with timestamp. This is OK.
In Java application, I suggested project team to use NamedNativeQueries wherein CAST as TIMESTAMP construct is specified in the query itself. Later on , I came to know that team cannot used NamedNativeQueries since queries are dynamic in nature. (Where condition can have 1 or 5 or no clauses).
Tried using Temporal.DATE annotation. Did not work. What i observed is that, we need to cast the date to timestamp while selecting itself. setMethod for the variable gets called after query has happened and if we do not do cast while doing select, value of 0001-01-01 gets changed to 2001-01-01.
Is there any way we can apply SQL constructs (similar to_date in Oracle ) before the query is executed?

Comment: <property name="date1" type="date" formula="CAST(date1 AS TIMESTAMP)">
<column name="date1" /> ..This was another solution I gave. But then this cannot be used in the project since they are not using XML mapping.

Comment: Got a solution. Missed a very straight forward Hibernate construct. Added @Formula("CAST(date as TIMESTAMP)") annotation. To make sure that where clause also forms correctly, an appropriate SQL restriction was added to the criteria.

Comment: Remember to have `@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)` rather than `@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)` in your Domain Object getter annotation. That was my problem for not receiving the timestamp from the Date.